# using SPSS syntax "if any" statements

Tags: syntax, spss

Is it possible to use an "if any" statement or some variation of it to specify that multiple variables of a list of variables meet the specified qualification?  For example, if with a normal "if any" statment I am specifying that one of a list of variables meets the qualification (i.e., if any (1, varx, varxx, varxxx) newvar=1.), I want to be able to specify that at least 5 of the 6 variables I list out meet the qualification.  Is that possible using an "if any" statement or will I need to just write a series of "if" statements for each of the possible permutations?

Answer (score 3):

The any function will be true if one or more of the variables meet the condition.
Take a look at COUNT command.  It counts the number of variables that meet a specified condition.  The Nmiss and Nvalid functions might also be helpful, and some of the functions have a count form that only returns a nonmissing value if at least that many variables meet specified criteria.  E.g., mean.3(x1 to x10) would only return a mean value if at least three variables are not missing.

HTH,
Jon Peck